# Recovering free space after zeroing out drive with sfill?

Tags: files

I was following a tutorial showing how to zero out the free space by using sfill .  It only occurred to me after the fact that I did this that if the free space is zeroed out, then of course I don't have any free space left on the drive.  Is there any way to recover the free space that was zeroed out on my drive?

Answer (score 1):

sfill fills (most of) the free space by creating temporary files, which it removes after use. The free space is still free afterwards.

Note that sfill doesn't just zero but makes a slow, 37-pass wipe. This is only necessary to protect against [attacks requiring expensive laboratory equipment and that have a slight chance of working only on long-obsolete hardware](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10464/why-is-writing-zeros-or-random-data-over-a-hard-drive-multiple-times-better-th/10474#10474). (It's possible that [*some* flash memory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37317/secure-wiping-of-eeprom-and-flash-memory) may require a multiple-pass wipe, but on flash memory, [overwriting with any pattern is not enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/is-it-enough-to-only-wipe-a-flash-drive-once), you need to TRIM, and you need to rely on your device's secure implementation of TRIMming.) `cat /dev/zero >zero; rm zero` is just as good in practice.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and a quick response. In your response you said that "the free space is still free afterwards" but `rootfs` is still showing 100% under USE% when running `df -h`. Did I misunderstand your response?

Comment: @user3150391 If `sfill` leaves the filesystem full when it exits, it means it crashed in the middle. Try `sfill -v` to see what it's doing. Is the exit status 0? What options did you use? Where did you install it from? Note that if you run it on your root filesystem, it may disrupt other programs that try to create files at the same time.